# How to move a footer menu 150 px to the right?

Tags: css, joomla-3.5

I want to move the footer menu 150 px to the right. Also please let me know which file to edit and what line. Otherwise I would be stuck with a code and I won't know what to do with it. Here's the link to live site:

idevsky.com

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it.
230 px is even better!
In this file:
templates/jp-x2/css/joomlaplates.css
In

```
.footer-outer {

margin-right:-230px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or similar for inspect your source code of your site in your browser.

A tool like this will give you information about the selectors and the path where they are located, the line number and the name of the file that contains this selectors.

Once you have this you can add or change the values, it's certainly a tool that will save you a large amount of work.